# How to get Day from birthdate of all members and display Day BirthDay Due on another dataGrid column eg. WednesDay,ThursDay etc

Tags: c#

Programmatically add new column to DataGridView showing Day from Birthdate

I have a DataGridView bound to a DataTable. The DataTable is populated from a database query.

```
        try
        {
            DateTime date;
            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("select Name,Dateofbirth from members where (DATE_FORMAT(Dateofbirth, '%m-%d') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m-%d') and DATE_FORMAT(Dateofbirth, '%m-%d') <= DATE_FORMAT((NOW() + INTERVAL +7 DAY), '%m-%d')) and Branch=@Branch", conn);
            sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Branch", lbladminbranch.Text.ToString());

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dataGridViewbirthday.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridViewbirthday.ForeColor = Color.Black;


            DataGridViewColumn BDay = new DataGridViewColumn();
            DataGridViewCell cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell(); //Specify which type of cell in this column
            BDay.CellTemplate = cell;
            BDay.HeaderText = "BirthDay";
            BDay.Name = "BirthDay";
            dataGridViewbirthday.Columns.Add(BDay);

            if (dataGridViewbirthday.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                dataGridViewbirthday.Columns["Dateofbirth"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";


                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewbirthday.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                     foreach (DataRow dr in dataGridViewbirthday.Rows)
                    {
                        date = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["Dateofbirth"].ToString());
                        dataGridViewbirthday.Columns["BirthDay"].ToString() = date.Date.Day;
                    }
            }

            else
            {
                dataGridViewbirthday.DataSource = null;
            }
            conn.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            conn.Close();
        }
```

I would like to programmatically add a new column to the DataGridView called BirthDay showing Day of birth based of BirthDate displayed in Dateofbirth column

Comment: Do you mean Day or DayOfWeek?

Comment: So you mean `DayOfWeeek` and not `Day` (which returns the day of the month, e.g. 13 for today). Anyway, what is the issue you're having with your current code?

Comment: want to return Day like Friday,Monday based on Birthdate like 25/10/1990

Comment: Anyway, what is the issue you're having with your current code?

Comment: Day not showing in third column (BirthDay) i added,the Due Day should be displayed in third column based on values in dateofbirth column eg. James Smith 23/5/1990 Saturday

Comment: Is anything displaying?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: Name and DateofBirth columns have values in field but BirthDay has no values,thats the only problem

Comment: I suggest to add the BirthDay value in the SELECT query itself so that it will be display in Grid. You don't need to add new column manually. `select Name, Dateofbirth, FORMAT(Dateofbirth, 'dddd') AS BirthDay from members where .... `

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya your solution is OK,but i want to first get the Day and Month part from Dateofbirth and Display which Day birthday is Due in Current year

Comment: How are you doing the same in C# Code?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Please Remember theres no Column Name BirthDay in Database ,i added it programmatically to display Day on which Upcoming BirthDay will fall based on Dateofbirth column in database

Comment: Did you try the SQL query approach which I suggested? You can get the Name of the day from BirthDate using SQL Function `FORMAT`. Try running `select Name, Dateofbirth, FORMAT(Dateofbirth, 'dddd') AS BirthDay from members` query in SQL Management Studio directly and see what result you get.

Comment: Please Check my answer below and have idea what i mean,the third columns (BirthDay) should display Day which birthday is due in current Year,not Day in Dateofbirth column in Database,thank you for your response

Comment: Did your answer below solve your problem?

Comment: `SELECT Name,Dateofbirth, FORMAT(Dateofbirth, 'dddd'), 
FORMAT(DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(year, GETDATE()), DATEPART(month, Dateofbirth), DATEPART(day, Dateofbirth)), 'dddd') 
AS BirthDay
FROM members`

Comment: Yes i was able to solve myself please review my code and have an idea what exactly i meant,Thank you for your support

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is this line

```
dataGridViewbirthday.Columns["BirthDay"].ToString() = date.Date.Day;
```

if you want to change value of cells in this column 
try this

```
dataGridViewbirthday.Columns["BirthDay"].Cells[index].Value = date.Date.Day.ToString()
```

Comment: Except that will show the day of the month (e.g. "13")

Comment: @John I;ve been able to work around this code ,only problem now is showing DayOfWeek in Third Added Column (BirthDay) to display the days,any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
try
        {
            DateTime date;
            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter("select Name,Dateofbirth from members where (DATE_FORMAT(Dateofbirth, '%m-%d') >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m-%d') and DATE_FORMAT(Dateofbirth, '%m-%d') <= DATE_FORMAT((NOW() + INTERVAL +7 DAY), '%m-%d')) and Branch=@Branch", conn);
            sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Branch", lbladminbranch.Text.ToString());

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dt.Columns.Add("BirthDay", typeof(string));
            dataGridViewbirthday.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridViewbirthday.ForeColor = Color.Black;

            if (dataGridViewbirthday.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
               dataGridViewbirthday.Columns["Dateofbirth"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";

                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridViewbirthday.Rows.Count; i++)
                { 
                date = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridViewbirthday[1, i].Value);

                DateTime birthday = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
                int day =birthday.Day;
                int month =birthday.Month;
                int CurrentYear = Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.Date.Year);

                String NewDay = day.ToString("00");
                String NewMonth = month.ToString("00");
                String Year = CurrentYear.ToString();
                String FullDate =Year + "/" + NewMonth + "/" + NewDay;

                DateTime CurrentDate = Convert.ToDateTime(FullDate);
                foreach(DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridViewbirthday.Columns)
                {
                        if (col.Name=="BirthDay")
                        {

                             dataGridViewbirthday["BirthDay", i].Value = CurrentDate.DayOfWeek.ToString();
                            //dataGridViewbirthday.Rows[i].Cells["BirthDay"].Value = CurrentDate.DayOfWeek.ToString();    
                        }   
                }

                }

                dataGridViewbirthday.Sort(dataGridViewbirthday.Columns[2], ListSortDirection.Descending);
            }

            else
            {
            dataGridViewbirthday.DataSource = null;
            }
            conn.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            conn.Close();
        }
```